# Custom keys in storyboard base localization files

Tags: ios, interface-builder, localizable.strings

I have a storyboard that needs to be internationalized and I want to determine if base internationalization would be of any use.

I plan to send only strings file to the translators and base internationalization allows text in storyboards to be localized using strings files, as opposed to having storyboard copies for each language. The drawback I see is that the generated string key-value pairs look something like this:

> "CT6-Ml-BFU.title" = "Bank";

where CT6-Ml-BFU is something called the object-ID. Now if I were to send these files to the translators there would not be enough context to translate the strings. For example the word "bank" could mean a financial institution or a river bank, depending on context. In a different language the two words might not be homonyms and different words would be used for the two meanings. Without context information it's impossible to translate.

The problem is that the string key value gives no information about where this string occurs, unless you have access to the storyboard and know how to search inside it.

Is there any way to define custom string keys or do I ultimately have to set the strings manually from code?

Comment: Have you found something interesting regarding to this? I'm looking forward to it